# Export Krita Layers to Single Images

Tags: export, save-as, drawing, krita

When I have multiple layers in Krita, how can I export each layer as an individual image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know I am a bit late, but Krita 4.1.0 (released this june) **does** have such  option.

Go to "Tools"->"Scripts"->"Export layers". There you can choose the folder and what to do with visible/invisible layers. The output image names are the layer names.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Works like a charm, and even nests layer images in subfolders when they're grouped in the layers palette.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct export option, however when saving in the .tif format, you can easily convert to separate .png files using Imagemagick's `convert`.

If you save the following image:

[image: Krita screenshot of layered drawing]

in the .tif format without flattening:

[image: Save as .tif Krita dialog]

and then convert to single images using:

```
convert layered.tif layers.png
```

you will then have the separate images:

[image]

Hopefully, installing Imagemagick won't be a [challenge](https://superuser.com/questions/44600/how-to-split-a-multipage-tiff-file-on-windows) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943947/imagemagick-can-not-find-deletegates-library-for-tiff-format-on-mac-os-x-mounta).

There also seems to be [a script](https://gist.github.com/jessevanherk/6ba7712eb64040a9ea2b) to convert from .ora, however saving as .org is very slow and a quick test of the script created results of much smaller resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to save a file in psd format and then use other editors (gimp, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I just did it manually by figuring out the dimensions of my canvas and creating a new project with the same dimensions. Then I copied and pasted each layer one at a time from the old project into the new one and went to file > export > and saved each layer under a different.png file name.

This was an easy solution for me that didn't involve installing other software, and I luckily only had 3 layers so it just took a few minutes. I can understand that this would be tedious with many layers, but I just thought I'd throw my answer out there for anyone with a simple project.

Answer (score 0):

Use File > Export > **Spriter SCML** - this command export all layers as files and all groups as folders