# How do I separate a TIFF stack into several PNGs or a single PDF?

Tags: conversion, imagemagick

I was at the library scanning pages of old newspaper articles and the microfilm scanner generated a TIFF stack.  Now I am back home I thought this was going to be easier but nothing sees past frame zero.  Is there a way to use convert from command line to separate all the images?  Just running convert crashes.

```
jonathan@weinraub:~$ convert nyt_1980_12_30.tif nyt%d.png
Killed
```

`2016-03-11T09:32:32-05:00 0:04.850 4.420u 6.8.9 Resource convert[1699]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/279/Resource
  Area: 119MB/119MB/4.2005GB
2016-03-11T09:32:32-05:00 0:04.850 4.420u 6.8.9 Resource convert[1699]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/279/Resource
  Memory: 119MB/1.1085GiB/1.956GiB
2016-03-11T09:32:32-05:00 0:04.850 4.420u 6.8.9 Cache convert[1699]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3606/Cache
  open nyt_1980_12_30.tif[9] (Heap Memory, 3400x4376 113.5MiB)
2016-03-11T09:32:32-05:00 0:04.850 4.420u 6.8.9 Resource convert[1699]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/279/Resource
  Memory: 59.51MB/1.164GiB/1.956GiB
2016-03-11T09:32:32-05:00 0:04.850 4.420u 6.8.9 Exception convert[1699]: tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/861/Exception
  Depreciated and troublesome old-style JPEG compression mode, please convert to new-style JPEG compression and notify vendor of writing software. OJPEGSetupDecode'
    Killed`

```
jonathan@weinraub:~$ which convert
/usr/bin/convert
jonathan@weinraub:~$ convert
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2015-01-05     http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl     lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib

Usage: convert [options ...] file [ [options ...] file ...] [options ...] file
```

Whats interesting, I tried on my RHEL server and I got different errors and it failed:

**update:**

`16:55:40 0:36 34.100u 6.2.8 Cache convert[27230]: cache.c/DestroyCacheInfo/1763/Cache
  destroy nyt_1980_12_30.tif[10]
16:55:40 0:36 34.120u 6.2.8 Resource convert[27230]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/801/Resource
  Memory: 1.1e+02mb/1.1e+02mb/5.9gb
16:55:40 0:36 34.120u 6.2.8 Cache convert[27230]: cache.c/DestroyCacheInfo/1763/Cache
  destroy nyt_1980_12_30.tif[11]
16:55:40 0:36 34.150u 6.2.8 Resource convert[27230]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/801/Resource
  Memory: 1.1e+02mb/0/5.9gb
16:55:40 0:36 34.150u 6.2.8 Cache convert[27230]: cache.c/DestroyCacheInfo/1763/Cache
  destroy nyt_1980_12_30.tif[12]
convert: nyt_1980_12_30.tif: unknown field with tag 512 (0x200) encountered. TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: nyt_1980_12_30.tif: unknown field with tag 513 (0x201) encountered. TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: nyt_1980_12_30.tif: unknown field with tag 514 (0x202) encountered. TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: nyt_1980_12_30.tif: unknown field with tag 519 (0x207) encountered. TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: nyt_1980_12_30.tif: unknown field with tag 520 (0x208) encountered. TIFFReadDirectory'.`

I used Ifranview in windows at work and i got it converted in the end.  But, I like to know why now on two systems, debian and rhel, it is failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming TIFF file is not splitable via imagemagick due to outdated jpeg format used as compression

Assuming a platform like Debian or Ubuntu

use the libtiff-tools package that supplies the utility `tiffsplit`

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff-tools
tiffsplit problematicfile.tif file
```

edit

JPEG is a kind of compression that TIFF supports.  Imagemagick seems to have problems with it sometimes. if the split files are still problematic, then the compression can be altered with a different libtiff tool, `tiffcp`which can use one of several other compression types with its -c switch

```
tiffcp -c lzw jpegedfile.tif  lzwedfile.tif
```

promoted from the comments (@Mint)

[Technote on why compression sometimes fails](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303165607/http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/TIFFTechNote2.html)

Comment: Note on why old jpeg format was messed up  http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/TIFFTechNote2.html

Comment: Unless I used it wrong, I got `TIFFReadRawStrip: Compression scheme does not support access to raw uncompressed data.`

Comment: was that on the tiffsplit or tiffcp?   tiffcp has a `-c none` switch.  You could try that on the whole stack before splitting.   Sounds like that jpeg compression was a bad idea for the programmer, even if they set it for lossless level of quality

Comment: That did the trick.  Interestingly enough, using the `tiffcp` then the `tiffsplit` separated the file into 14 tiff files.  using convert on the `tiffscp` only generated two PNGs before being killed

Comment: For anyone looking to read the TIFFTechNote2.html page from the first comment, it's still up on the internet archive (as remotesensing.org has closed down) https://web.archive.org/web/20160303165607/http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/TIFFTechNote2.html

Answer (score 0):

See [How to split a multipage TIFF file on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/44600/how-to-split-a-multipage-tiff-file-on-windows)

but use the convert to make PNGs instead

```
convert multipage.tif single%d.png
```

Comment: It still gets killed.  I edited my original question to show.

Comment: Maybe turning on debug logging will provide some insight `convert -debug all nyt_1980_12_30.tif nyt%d.png`

Comment: you might even verify that your path is such that running `convert` is imagemagick's convert.  A verb like convert may be used by something else as a command name

Comment: Wow, if that's an abort on a depreciated feature of JPEG, that's pretty hash.

Comment: People were complaining about it here:  http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16155

Comment: As a possible work around, perhaps expanding to jpegs won't decompress the jpgs, and they will just be split out verbatim.   That might skip over the decompression error.  Then you can try other tools to convert to png.

Comment: Is this TIFF file something you are willing to share online?  IIRC it was about a GB.  too large for email, but maybe you have someplace you can leave it out for download

Comment: Thats the thing, its only 14 pages long or so, 44 meg.  Not sure why it is failing.  I tried to use jpg and it still fails.  As well as on rhel where it then gives me `convert: Sorry, requested compression method is not configured. `nyt_1980_12_30.tif'.`

Comment: Well, that's a better error message than 'Killed'   If I had a copy I thought I might try throwing perl Imager::File::TIFF at it, or seeing if libtiff in C chokes on it

Comment: If you do a `strings` on it, do you see the "JPEG" that magic-numbers the JPEG header for each image.   If so, a dirty way to split it might be to just hack out chunks based on the address of those boundaries  (darn it `strings` looks for 5 characters in a row I think.  use `xxd` and search for JPEG instead)

Comment: now after thinking about it during a drive home, I bet the JPEGs are preview images, while the data you want is in actual TIFF image areas.   I'm off to see if there is some way to strip previews from TIFFs

Comment: that makes sense, i was wondering why there is jpeg data in a lossless file format.