# How to Split a Multipage Tiff File on Macintosh?

Tags: mac, macos-sierra, tiff, image-conversion

I see a [similar question here](https://superuser.com/q/44600/9461), but it in for Windows.

How can I break out a page of a multipage tiff file on Mac OS X Sierra?  I've got Photoshop CS6 and Illustrator CS6 and Acrobat Pro DC, but none of them appear to be up to the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the tiff file in Preview.  It works in versions 5-9 and in Mac OS at least back as far as Snow Leopard.  Make sure the thumbnails are visible in the sidebar.  Click and drag the thumbnail to the desktop or folder of your choice.  Example: Page 27 of the multipage tiff file "Mammoth Mining 2 - pp 001-029 0086DD76.tiff" will yield the file "Mammoth Mining 2 - pp 001-029 0086DD76-27 (dragged).tiff". This avoids creating a PDF file and using Acrobat Pro DC.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by opening up the tif file in the Mac's `Preview` Version 9.0 (909.18) application on Mac OS X Sierra.  Once opened, I used the menu `File -> Export...` and in the file dialog chose `Format:` PDF.  This created a PDF file which I was easily able to break out the one page I needed in Acrobat Pro DC.